# Is knowing Cars 2 required to fully enjoy Cars 3?

Tags: suggested-order, cars-2, cars, cars-3

I have a DVD with the first Disney/Pixar Cars movie. My nearly 3 years old son watches it all over again. We did not see Cars 2. I'd like to take him to cinema for Cars 3.

Are there many references to Cars 2? Will we get confused or fail to catch all the funny moments?

Comment: Why not just rent or stream *Cars 2* first, then go see Cars 3 in the theater the following week or something?

Comment: In general, kids' movies do not have complicated references, or even require the child to remember the previous movie well. Any reference that is made is completely optional, anything needed for the plot of the current movie will be stated explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Cars 3 doesn't reference Cars 2 at all.

Cars 3 is more of a direct sequel to Cars (the first one).

Comment: Now after years of expertise in watching all Cars movies I can confirm that was a perfect answer to my original question :-)